# Ruby: capture and reuse block of HTML code in ERB template

Tags: ruby, erb

Note that I cannot use Rails or Javascript.

Is there any way to repeat a block of HTML code using **only Ruby / ERB**?

In Rails I would do this:

```
<% content_for :mycontent do %>
  some html code
  that I want to capture
  etc
<% end %>

Then, here, in the same template, I can reuse the block...

<%= content_for :mycontent %>

Multiple times...

<%= content_for :mycontent %>
```

Is there any equivalent without Rails?

Comment: If what you're asking is if ERB has built in functionality which matches content_tag the answer is no. There are is most likely several gems with similiar functionality but that makes the question off topic and you can also create something similiar for example by reverse engineering Rails (thats the glory of open source after all).

Comment: Also avoid "is it possible questions?" - the answer is almost always Yes and its not a real question. Most answerers avoid them since they lead to the low effort followup "But then how do I do it?" question and the help vampire deluge of follow up comments.

Comment: @max I mean, with pure Ruby/ERB, not with gems... I thought that maybe there was a simple equivalent. There are similar questions, like *"What is an equivalent of blank? without Rails?"* and they have useful replies... Maybe there is also a simple alternative to `content_for`